# Flutter Dev Tools not displaying correctly

Tags: dart

I'm new to Flutter & Dart and busy learning it.

My develop environment is xUbutu using VS Code with Flutter and Dart installed.

Flutter 2.10.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision db747aa133 (5 days ago) • 2022-02-09 13:57:35 -0600
Engine • revision ab46186b24
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2

When running a simple app in debug mode and when I "Open DevTools in my Chrome browser", I get the following:
[image]

In VS Code, I'm able to scroll the complete widget tree:
[image]

My problem is that I do not get the complete widget tree in my Chrome browser and I can't scroll.

Regards,

Nols Smit

Comment: No problem when using FireFox.